# Query Explorer - Extracting Product Performance Report Metrics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Trying to pull product performance report metrics as shown here: [image: metrics]

It work for previous month but not for the current (Feb) why would this happen?

Comment: could be that your data collection has broken down?